# Recognizing a subquery in a javascript string

Tags: javascript, mysql, database

I have a script that takes a query as a string, then appends the query to add the database name to any listed table.  The purpose is so that I can run one large query using Sequel Pro that will search all of the databases on the server, without me needing to run the query on each individual database or play around with sqldumps.  So far, it works great...except for when dealing with subqueries.

Using a query such as:

```
SELECT apple FROM basket
```

the script will properly append it so that it comes out as

```
SELECT apple FROM db_name.basket
```

However, if I try something like

```
SELECT apple FROM (SELECT fruit FROM basket) tmpTableA
```

it appends the name to the starting parenthesis

```
SELECT apple FROM db_name.(SELECT fruit FROM db_name.basket) tmpTableA
```

But I need it to be something more like this:

```
SELECT apple FROM (SELECT fruit FROM db_name.basket) tmpTableA
```

So far, I haven't figured out how to identify and skip subqueries that immediately follow a FROM statement while still appending in front of regular tables that follow a FROM statement.  Here's that snippet from my script: (dbList is an array containing the name of each of the databases on the server)

```
for (count = 0; count < dbList.length; count++){
  var dbName = "`" + dbList[count] + "`";
  var rawSQL = userQuery + "<br>"; //userQuery pulls from the input and converts to lowercase
  rawSQL = rawSQL.replace(/ from /ig, " from " + dbName + ".");
  rawSQL = rawSQL.replace(/ join /ig, " join " + dbName + ".");
  strSQL += rawSQL; //strSQL is later displayed on the page for the user
  if (count < dbList.length - 1){
        strSQL += "UNION<br>";
  }
}
```

Comment: In the general case this would require what amounts to a SQL parser.

Comment: This isn't answer to your question as much as it is a warning - this sounds like a really roundabout form of SQL injection - an attack waiting to happen because, presumably you're sending this query to the database. Can you ensure it's safe?

Comment: It's as safe as one of our internal employees who already has access to the db.

This is an in-house script that just serves to conveniently take a query we feed it and generate one large query that we then copy and paste into a read-only copy of the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a bad idea so be careful.

In the code below I use `String#replace` and a regex.
The regex looks for `FROM` followed by one or more space characters followed by a single character that's not a `(` or `)` and saves that character in a capturing group. It then replaces the entire match with `FROM db_name.$1` where `$1` is the text captured in the capturing group.

This can be modified to handle other types of queries, or you could just use multiple regex patterns.

```js
let q = "SELECT apple FROM (SELECT fruit FROM basket) tmpTableA"

let newQ = q.replace(/FROM\s+([^\(\)])/gi, "FROM db_name.$1");

console.log(newQ);
```

Comment: *"This is probably a bad idea so be careful."* -> **Yes**, it is.

Comment: OP's comments seem to suggest that they know what they're doing.and that they are assuming the risk. Not sure why this answer was downvoted.

Comment: Thanks, that resolved the issue.  Yes, I know it is a bad idea, but we are talking about a script that is run locally and doesn't directly touch anything (database or external website included).  It's basically just a tool slapped together to make things easier for an internal team.  Thanks for your help, @KhauriMcClain!